# How to change visual studio file tab view

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ide

I accidentally pressed something and my visual studio file tab view changed. PFA images to how I want my file tab to be viewed in the original Image and how my current file tab view in actual Image. Please let me know how to reset this setting. Thanks in advance.

**Actual Image**
[image: Actual Image]

**Orginal Image**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by following steps:

1. Open Workspace Settings
   On Windows/Linux - File > Preferences > Settings.
   On macOS - Code > Preferences > Settings.
2. Search keyword "showTabs"
3. It should show this following config with being untick

```
"workbench.editor.showTabs": false
```

Change this config to true. It's also the default one.

We can follow many issues of VSCode [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/)